# Capture entire Windows sound output?

Tags: java, audio, stream, javasound

I have had a look at the `AudioSystem` class but can't seem to figure out how I would go about getting the output stream of the audio in Windows, i.e. what you hear coming out of the speakers?

Then I want to be able to get this input stream and then output it again to a different stream, essentially sending a secondary copy of all sound to another device so that it then can be played?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Capturing Audio](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/capturing.html) in the Java Tutorial.

Look through the various data lines of the system to discover the one that combines all the sounds.  If no software or hardware 'audio loop-back' is enabled, Java will fail to detect it.

Comment: Could you possibly give me a code example? Can the audio be sent over a socket's stream after the line has been found?